# How to fix uid in NFC

Tags: android, tags, nfc, uniqueidentifier, nexus-s

I want to fix uid for nexus s and when use the phone to tag at NFC shield. The shield will show id. But when it tag at the nfc shield, id is not same. Can I fix my uid ?

Answer (score 5):

What you likely see is the NFCID: the NFC peer-to-peer ID. This ID is randomly generated anew by the NFC hardware on every NFC connection and cannot be fixed.

Comment: Do you have reference for this? Because My professor want to see it.

Comment: This is a property of this specific NFC chip. Other NFC chips may behave differently. So I don't think there is any independent reference

Answer (score 1):

The current SDK does not allow you to use card emulation, so you can't use the phone as tag.

Answer (score 0):

Because the ID changes for the peer-to-peer on every connection, you'll have to define an NDEF record with a text value in it. Make that value your fixed ID. On the other side, on the shield, you'll need to read out that record to find your fixed value/ID.

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C/tree/master/examples has some examples on how to manipulate NDEF records but only on MiFare classics. If you're using Ultralights or other kinds of tags, this will be different.

Comment: If you want to edit/write some NDEF messages, there is always [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/).